# Google Analytics - Using Regex Filter URL with Request URI

Tags: regex, google-analytics

We want to filter the profile with Request URI. Can someone guide me on how to write a regex that will select only these (?c=/us) parameters from the below url. 
www.xyx.com/?c=/us

Comment: the parameter should start immediately after the domain (com) to make sure we don't pass any other parameters that starts somewhere middle in the URI

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=\/)(\?[^\?]+)
```

Question mark `?` should be escaped since it has a specific meaning in regex.

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/wSrsmKKBuk)